# What does it mean connect to aspmx.l.google.com:25: Network is unreachable?

Tags: postfix

I have server with RHEL 6 and postfix (postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6), When I try to send email to Google I'm getting this in /var/logmaillog:

```
postfix/smtp[13414]: 6F4DC10406E7: to=<XXX@englishonlineuniversity.com>, relay=none, delay=0.16, delays=0.02/0/0.14/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

This error occurs only on this domain (englishonlineuniversity.com).

What does it mean connect to aspmx.l.google.com:25: Network is unreachable?

Answer (score 23):

This means your MTA is trying to connect to the Google SMTP via IPv6 (2a00:1450:4013:c01::1b). This doesn't work as your network probably doesn't support IPv6.

To get rid of the error message, you can configure Postfix not to use IPv6 by editing your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` with this directive:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Afterwards you'll have to restart postfix:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Comment: It probably means that there is some issue with his name resolution, or routing to the IPv4 MX also, as unless you configure postfix as IPv6 only, it will always try the IPv4 answers, then the IPv6 responses.

Comment: To be able to tell that, one would need to see the rest of the log. The provided line only tells that IPv6 connection is not working. Perhaps the mail is delivered via IPv4 in the next line. As far as I know, postfix will per default try IPv6 first, then IPv4 as fallback: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_address_preference

Comment: You're right, that has changed, as specified here: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_protocols

Comment: This won't help, when the problem really is that the server isn't connected to the Internet.

Comment: You can also use `smtp_address_preference = ipv4` instead of completely disabling ipv6

Answer (score 1):

Some ISPs don't allow localhost as a domain name (QFDN) and will reject incoming email from your server. In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` alter the following:

```
myhostname = localhost
```

to a fully qualified domain name you own, i.e:

```
myhostname = geoip-db.com
mydestination = geoip-db.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```